# TinyMCE - Submenus are displayed at top of the screen when editor is in a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, react-modal

I'm using TinyMCE 5.0.2 (self hosted) and adding the editor via the Official [TinyMCE React Component](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react).  I've put my editor in a modal created with [React Modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal).  The problem is all of the submenus are showing up at the top of the screen (fixed) instead of relative to the menu item.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

I started a JSFiddle here but I can't get ReactTinymce to accept props the way it does in a regular project in the fiddle.  (The ReactTinyMCE onEditorChange method doesn't trigger and the value doesn't get set, I assume I'm not using it right but fiddles are strange sometimes...)

https://jsfiddle.net/cleanshooter/9qutaz3o/60/

```
const modalStyle = {
  content : {
    top                   : '25%',
    left                  : '25%',
    right                 : 'auto',
    bottom                : 'auto'
  }
};

class View extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false,
      content: 'Init'
    };
    this.updateContent = this.updateContent.bind(this);
  }

  openModalHandler() {
    this.setState({isModalOpen: true});
  }

  closeModalHandler() {
    this.setState({isModalOpen: false});
  }

  updateContent(value) {
    console.log('changed: ', value);
    this.setState({content: value})
  }

    render() {

    return (
    <div>
      <h2>TinyMCE in a React-Modal Example</h2>
      <button onClick={this.openModalHandler.bind(this)}>Open modal</button>
      <ReactModal 
        isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
        style={modalStyle}
        onRequestClose={this.closeModalHandler.bind(this)}>
        <ReactTinymce
          value={this.state.content}
          onEditorChange={value => this.updateContent(value)}
        />
        <button onClick={this.closeModalHandler.bind(this)}>Close</button>
      </ReactModal>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactModal.setAppElement('#app')
ReactDOM.render(<View name="React" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In TinyMCE 5 popups are inside an element attached to the end of the body. Their position is calculated to line up with the editor container when they open.

I'm not familiar with React Modal but it's quite possible something about the styles is interfering with our position calculations. Can you create a sample page for us to investigate (perhaps using one of the react modal demo pages)?

This appears to be a bug, if you could log a github ticket with the sample page that would be awesome.

Comment: sample created and added to question... need some help with the ReactTinymce component though... not functioning as expected.

Comment: TinyMCE menus appear normal in the fiddle, is that related to the ReactTinymce issues you're having?

Note that you're not using the official TinyMCE react package on that page. There are multiple packages claiming to offer TinyMCE support in react, sadly, it can be quite confusing to pick the correct one.

Comment: what IS the official TinyMCE react package?

Comment: The one you linked in your question: @tinymce/tinymce-react
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react

Comment: ahhh... well the unpkg is a CDN for everything on NPM and as you can see I'm using the minified distro for version 0.7.0.  Which is why I ask, when using JSFiddle, what is the "Official Package" if it's not the one that's been released on NPM?

Comment: I know what unpkg is, your fiddle is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinymce instead of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react which you did mention in your question. There are five or six "tinymce react" packages on NPM, there's not much we can do about the duplication.

Comment: Thanks for catching that and the clarification... I'm new to unpkg.  I'm having trouble using @tinymce/tinymce-react in JSFiddle... look like you guys don't have an AMD distro.  Anyway I could convince you to make one?  I'm not super familiar with TypeScript but I will try and create a pull request.